# recharts line chart 'Y' axis range issue

Tags: reactjs, bar-chart, recharts

I have a line chart that displays several lines of data, everything works as expected, the only issue is that when the chart is displayed there is huge blank space inside the chart itself, I have been checking the data range I am sending but seems fine, all values appear, have been also checking for some styling issue but I dont seem to see anything strange, sadly the docs are very limited for the styling regard that I am not able yet to find a solution.

```
<ResponsiveContainer aspect={10.0 / 3.0}>
          <LineChart margin={{left: 30, top: 30}} width={730} height={300}>
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
            <XAxis
              dataKey="month"
              type="category"
              allowDuplicatedCategory={false}
              allowDecimals={false}
            />
            <YAxis
              padding={{top: 28}}
              interval={0}
              ticks={range}
              tickSize={2}
              tickFormatter={val => getLocaleString(val)}
              label={{
                value: 'EUR',
                position: {x: 40, y: 0},
                className: 'chart__label',
              }}
            />
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend
              onMouseOver={mouseOverLegend}
              onMouseLeave={mouseLeaveLegend}
            />
            {data.map((data, index) => {
              const namePostfix = `EUR ${yearsDataChart[index]}`
              const stroke =
                hoverIndex === index || !legendHover
                  ? colorsChart[index]
                  : COLOR_HOVER
              const costName = `${translate('cost')} ${namePostfix}`
              const revenueName = `${translate('revenue')} ${namePostfix}`

              return [
                <>
                  <Line
                    dataKey="revenue"
                    data={data}
                    name={revenueName}
                    stroke={stroke}
                  />
                  <Line
                    dataKey="cost"
                    data={data}
                    name={costName}
                    stroke={
                      hoverIndex === index || !legendHover
                        ? colorsChartProvider[index]
                        : stroke
                    }
                  />
                </>,
              ]
            })}
          </LineChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
```

the result is :

[image]

hope someone has an idea of what could be the issue here

Comment: How is the value of range being calculated?